# How to get string representation of cassandra timestamp column?

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-php-driver

I'm querying a timestamp column from datastax php diver for cassandra

```
select name , x_date from table;
```

The result is returned in json format

```
name: "name"
x_date: {type: {name: "timestamp"}, seconds: 1561645740, microseconds: 0}
```

I want to get simple string representation of date formatted like `YYYY-mm-dd` as it appears on cql client not json.

I've tried `TODATE` function but same result is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search i found that class Cassandra\Timestamp included in datastax driver for php has a function toDateTime() that convert the json into php datetime format

```
 $datetime = x_date->toDateTime();
```

then i used format() to get my date formatted

```
 $myPhpDate = $datetime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```